# JavaScript - Counting number of characters in a div and skip tag inside it

Tags: javascript

The purpose is to add three dots after 55 char in a `<p/>` text.
The `<p>` may have more tags inside it like `<b/>`, `<i/>`, `<a/>`, etc those need to skip while counting. Once the count completed I want the assign the counted text with its original tags, see the desired output below.

e.g

```
<p><i>Every story has a beginning.</i> Discover how <b>company</b> began in 1996 and grew into a global design house at the forefront of <i>innovative</i> material design and expert <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">craftsmanship</a>.</p>
```

Desire Output:

```
<p><i>Every story has a beginning.</i> Discover how <b>company began</b>...</p>
```

I'm using pure JavaScript (no jQuery)!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why JavaScript? Why that magic number? Why not [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)?

Comment: isnt https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp sufficient?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to truncate text based upon the number of characters. but actual width of the text, because some characters are wider then others, for example 55 m's compared to 55 i's. In the extreme case  this is also one character, imagine 55 of these.

Comment: Why is began in the <b> tag? I would expect it to finish with a closing tag for the <p>

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked something out that might help. It stops counting on '<' and starts again on '>', so ignores tags and only counts enclosed characters. It also tracks every open tag and removes it when a tag is closed, so at the end it closes all tags that remain open...

```
const cutString = (str) => {

  let stringCount = 0
  let keepCounting = true
  let ans = ''
  let openTags = []

  for (let i = 0; i<str.length; i++){

    if (str[i] == "<") {
      keepCounting = false
      if (str[i+1] != `/`) openTags.push(str[i+1])
      continue
    }
    if (str[i] == ">") {
      keepCounting = true
      if (str[i-2] == `/`) openTags.splice(openTags.indexOf(str[i-2]), 1)
      continue
    }
    if (keepCounting) stringCount++
    if (stringCount == 56) {
      ans = str.slice(0, i)
      break
    }
  }

  openTags.forEach(tag => ans = ans+`</${tag}>`)
  
  
  return ans + "..."
}

let testString = `<p><i>Every story has a beginning.</i> Discover how <b>company</b> began in 1996 and grew into a global design house at the forefront of <i>innovative</i> material design and expert <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">craftsmanship</a>.</p>`


console.log(cutString(testString))
```

Output:

```
"<p><i>Every story has a beginning.</i> Discover how <b>company</b> began</p>..."
```

Comment: and it should work for all tag, like not for <p> as well?

Comment: with your fn. input: <h3>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some formThere are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form.</h3>
Output: <h3>There are many variations of passa...</h3>

Comment: Maybe there was a white space before the <h3> tag. in that case can we remove it too?

Comment: I have posted a new question on this here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748805/javascript-truncate-innerhtml-string-after-n-numbers-of-characters-with-strip